# Jersey - What is the difference in injecting UriInfo as class instance variable and injecting it as method parameter?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I came across injecting UriInfo in two ways -

```
@Path("/users/")
public class UsersResource {

@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;

...

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONArray getUsersAsJsonArray() {
}
```

Another way is -

```
@Path("/users/")
public class UsersResource {
...

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONArray getUsersAsJsonArray(@Context
UriInfo uriInfo) {

}
```

What is the preferred way to inject UriInfo? Is Jersey resources instantiated per request Or it is Singleton? If it is Singleton, then would it be good to use 2nd approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaig, there is no preferred way for injecting UriInfo. It more or less depends on programming style guidelines you working or not working with. The injection should work while you are working in Jersey-managed components.
 
I for one, prefer the field injection variant.

*Please note:* The object you will inject isn't UriInfo itself, it's a proxy pointing on the UriInfo for the current request. You can just picture it as a direct hotline to your container/connector.

The default scope is `Request Scoped`.

---

[Rules of Injection](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2401) in Jersey User Guide gives us the following informations:

**Class fields**
Inject value directly into the field of the class. The field can be private and must not be final. Cannot be used in Singleton scope except proxiable types mentioned above. Proxys are: `HttpHeaders`, `Request`, `UriInfo`, `SecurityContext` ...

**Constructor parameters**
The constructor will be invoked with injected values. If more constructors exists the one with the most injectable parameters will be invoked. Cannot be used in Singleton scope except proxiable types mentioned above.

**Resource methods**
The resource methods (these annotated with @GET, @POST, ...) can contain parameters that can be injected when the resource method is executed. Can be used in any scope.

**Sub resource locators**
The sub resource locators (methods annotated with @Path but not @GET, @POST, ...) can contain parameters that can be injected when the resource method is executed. Can be used in any scope.

**Setter methods**
Instead of injecting values directly into field the value can be injected into the setter method which will initialize the field. This injection can be used only with @Context annotation. This means it cannot be used for example for injecting of query params but it can be used for injections of request. The setters will be called after the object creation and only once. The name of the method does not necessary have a setter pattern. Cannot be used in Singleton scope except proxiable types mentioned above.

---

Hope this was helpful ... have a nice day!

Comment: thanks @zyexal. So for UriInfo it does not matter if I use class field level inject OR Resource method level injection since it is proxiable types of variable.

Comment: Yap, it doesn't matter 'cause the visibility and accessibility is always the same - you accessing a proxy. As far as jersey was able to inject the proxy :)